# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: sql

AFter building and hosting one of my zend application website, few days after, when tring to load the website, it resolves: ' No such file or directory ' on the homepage.

then i had to check up the error log. i got some error logs below

here is the error log file report:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'No such file or directory' in /home/dmgexpre/k/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php:333
Stack trace:

kindly, how can this be resolved

Comment: Have you checked line 333 in /home/dmgexpre/k/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php ?

Comment: Typically means the MySQL socket file is gone or moved. Make sure MySQL is running.